# Como concatenar sublistas de uma lista e somar valores nas mesmas usando Linq com C#

Tags: c#, linq

Olá, tenho as seguintes 2 classes:

```
public class EstoqueItem {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Qtd { get; set; }
    public Estoque Estoque { get; set;}
}

public class Estoque {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EstoqueItem> Itens { get; set; }
}
```

Em determinado momento, eu retorno uma `List<Estoque>` e preciso agrupar todos os `ICollection<EstoqueItem>` pelo Id e somar suas quantidades. Seria algo como a SQL abaixo:

```
SELECT Id, SUM(Qtd) as Qtd,
FROM EstoqueItem
WHERE /* as condições que retornam a lista aqui */
GROUP BY Id
```

Como faço para concatenar as sublistas do estoque, agrupando pelo id e somando suas quantidades no final?

Comment: A sua estrutura não faz muito sentido... entro do Estoque você tem vários items e cada um tem sua quantidade?

Comment: Tenho vários estoques e esses estoques tem vários itens únicos. Essa é só uma parte da estrutura em si (talvez por isso não faça sentido pra você), ela tem esse formato porque estou criando um projeto pra uma empresa de logística

Comment: Tentei simplificar ao máximo a estrutura do meu problema pra chegar em uma solução viável...

Comment: E essa referência "cíclica"? Um Item possui um estoque e um Estoque possui uma coleção de itens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vc pode usar o [SelectMany](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany)

Exemplo:

```
estoques.SelectMany(x => x.Itens)
        .GroupBy( i=> i.Id)
        .Select(g => new { Id = g.Key, Total = g.Sum(x => x.Qtd) });
```

Comment: ok mas e o `i.Count()` ? eu preciso somar as quantidades que estão nos itens para saber quanto itens de "x" id eu tenho para essa seleção

Comment: Entendi, neste caso vc vai precisar do groupby, editei a resposta com uma possível solução.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa usar o método `SelectMany` para fazer o que chama de "concatenar as listas" e depois disso fazer o agrupamento pelo Id do item e depois somar as quantidades.

Assim

```
var gp = estoques.SelectMany(x => x.Itens)
                 .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
                 .Select(x => new { Id = x.Key, Qtd = x.Sum(y => y.Qtd) });
```

<sup>**[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/r3ItA7)**</sup>

- **`SelectMany`** "achata" o resultado para uma lista de `EstoqueItem`
- **`GroupBy`** será aplicado nesta lista de `EstoqueItem` e retornará uma coleção onde cada item terá uma chave, sendo esta o valor da propriedade definida como agrupador (`Id`, no exemplo) e terá uma coleção de itens relacionados a esta chave. A partir desta coleção de itens (lista de `EstoqueItem`, neste caso) você pode aplicar qualquer operação valida com coleções
- **`Select`** faz com que cada item do resultado seja mapeado para um novo objeto onde a propriedade `Id` se refere à chave de cada item do agrupamento e a propriedade `Qtd` se refere ao resultado da operação `Sum(x => x.Qtd)` (somar a propriedade `Qtd` para cada item da coleção) em cima do valor do agrupamento

Comment: Tem algo na pergunta q eu acho que induz a um erro. No exemplo em SQL a consulta faz o Group pelo Id do Item e soma o Qtd, mas se Id do item é a chave, não vai somar, vai sempre trazer o Qtd por Id. Acho que faz mais sentido agrupar pelo Id do Estoque e não pelo Id do EstoqueItem.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar um `Sum` na seleção para somar as quantidades em cada estoque

```
// estoques => representa a sua coleção de estoques ou a entidade do EF

foreach (var e in estoques.Select(x => new { Key = x.Id, Sum = x.Itens.Sum(y => y.Qtd) }))
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Estoque: {0}, Total: {1}", e.Key, e.Sum));
}
```

Exemplo no [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/a3Jb9q)